# SQLite JDBC database in resource folder will not update

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am trying to update a database located in the resource folder of a module in intelliJ.

I can connect to the database and SELECT queries work i.e. getUpdateTime() functions correctly.

Using a GUI I am able to manually INSERT rows into the tables of the database. I am also able to INSERT rows using SQL UPDATE queries in the GUI.

But when I call insertAccountValue() nothing is added to the database. There is no StackTrace printed and "ADDED" prints to the console.

Here's my code...

```
public class LocalDatabase {

    private static Statement stat;
    private static Connection conn;

    // Connects to the Local Database used for saving data
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + LocalDatabase.class.getClassLoader().getResource("DashboardDatabase.db"));
            stat = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("CONNECTED TO LOCAL");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static long getUpdateTime() {
        try {
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT time FROM account_values ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;");
            if (rs.next())
                return rs.getLong("time");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void insertAccountValue(long time, String account, int value) {
        try {
            stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO account_values VALUES (12, 'test', 1212, 12);");
            stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO account_values VALUES (" + time + ", '"
                    + account.replaceAll("'", "''") + "', " + value + ");");
            System.out.println("ADDED");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection() {
        try {
            stat.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `LocalDatabase.class.getClassLoader().getResource("DashboardDatabase.db")`. At runtime it may be pointing somewhere other than where you expect.

Comment: Check Connection#getAutoCommit(), is it is false, you need to commit manualy